# Expression manipulation with exponential

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have the following expression

```
a + b + c + x + y + z + r*E^m + s/E^m + t*E^n + u/E^n
```

I want to extract the coefficients of exponential terms as well as the constants as a whole.

My output should be something like

```
{a + b + c + x + y + z,r,s,t,u}
```

I tried with

```
Coefficient[a + b + c + x + y + z + r*E^m + s/E^m + t*E^n + u/E^n,{E^m,E^-m,E^n,E^-n}]
```

But it only gave

```
{r, s, t, u}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight from the documentation:

> Coefficient[expr,*form*,0] picks out terms that are not proportional to *form*.

```
Coefficient[a + b + c + x + y + z + r*E^m + s/E^m + t*E^n + u/E^n,E,{0,m,-m,n,-n}] // Print
(* {a + b + c + x + y + z, r, s, t, u} *)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcc7CoAwEEXRraTWCXEPYm8vCjFETDEjxBH84NrjA4vD5bLXNbLXFHwp7RaXJYUURQdvajNDgBMuuCFX3cTo7v4qXtADL9TR0xCTZRKy8o7GOdPnJFrKBw)

Comment: Thanks. It has worked.